# How to always show tooltip in Chartjs 3?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, chart.js

I am creating a pie chart with Chartjs 3. I want the chart to always show the tooltips like this:
[image]

It's what I have found online in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q15ta78q/ , but it's made with Chartjs 2 and when I change the resource to Chartjs 3 in the fiddle, it shows some errors. Finally, I tried using the callbacks there in my Chartjs 3 function and also some references from https://codepen.io/kurkle/pen/BajeybZ?editors=0010 and https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/7672 . But the codepen one isn't working as what I expect.

I also have tried putting the `events: ['load']`, but it still doesn't work as expected.

Here's what I have tried so far:

```js
var data = {
labels: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
datasets: [
    {
        data: [10, 20, 15],
        backgroundColor: ['#ff0000','#00ff00', '#00f']
    },
]
}

var plugins = {
            
  legend: {
    position: 'top',
  },
  title: {
    display: true,
    text: 'Chart.js Pie Chart'
  },
  beforeRender: function (chart) {
    if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {
      // create an array of tooltips
      // we can't use the chart tooltip because there is only one tooltip per chart
      chart.pluginTooltips = [];
      chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
        chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach(function (sector, j) {
          chart.pluginTooltips.push(new Chart.Tooltip({
            _chart: chart.chart,
            _chartInstance: chart,
            _data: chart.data,
            _options: chart.options,
            _active: [sector]
          }, chart));
        });
      });

      // turn off normal tooltips
      chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false;
    }
  },
  afterDraw: function (chart, easing) {
    if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {
      // we don't want the permanent tooltips to animate, so don't do anything till the animation runs atleast once
      if (!chart.allTooltipsOnce) {
        if (easing !== 1)
          return;
        chart.allTooltipsOnce = true;
      }

      // turn on tooltips
      chart.options.tooltips.enabled = true;
      Chart.helpers.each(chart.pluginTooltips, function (tooltip) {
        tooltip.initialize();
        tooltip.update();
        // we don't actually need this since we are not animating tooltips
        tooltip.pivot();
        tooltip.transition(easing).draw();
      });
      chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false;
    }
  }
};

var options = 
    {
        showAllTooltips: true,
        plugins: plugins
    }

var context = $('#chart').get(0).getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(context, {type: 'pie', data: data, options: options});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.0.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer">
    <canvas id="chart" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
</div>
```

How to get all tooltips always show up after load and not getting effect from any mouse actions?

Comment: You probably just want to use [Datalabels plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-datalabels) instead of showing multiple tooltips.

Comment: @Jesper I want it to show like that tooltip, including the "bubble", not just the number. Can datalabels do this?

Comment: I know you can get the shape, position and color right. I'm not sure about the little "arrow"  that tooltips have.

Comment: @Jesper Thanks. May give it a try. Actually, I just want to enforce the tooltip to always show in the chart and get rid of the mouse interaction of the default tooltip itself.

Comment: If you want the exact same tooltip, you are best off to almost copy paste the internal tooltip plugin, adjust it to show all tooltips always and use that and then disable the default tooltip

Comment: @LeeLenalee I can't understand what you said above, Would you mind explaining and elaborating in detail and step-by-step about it?

Comment: The tooltip is a plugin that's in the core lib, so what you can do is copy that source code and make your own plugin by adjusting a few lines so all the tooltips show all the time. Then in your config you can disable the default tooltip so it doesn't trigger on hover